# Получаю странный ответ от сервера

Tags: python, requests

```
import requests

def get():
    headers_options = {
        'authority': 'cyberbank-vk.ru',
        'path': '/get',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'access-control-request-headers': 'content-type,vk-auth',
        'origin': 'https://bitva.vercel.app',
        'referer': 'https://bitva.vercel.app/',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.105 YaBrowser/21.3.2.178 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
        'token': 'token'

    }
    response = requests.post('https://cyberbank-vk.ru/get', headers = headers_options, json = {'to': '""'})
    return response

response  = get().text
print(response)
```

Получаю ответ:
[image: Текст]

Должно быть:
`{"balance":17,"contract":7,"nextContract":1619148729609,"banned":false,"money":0,"army":[{"power":1, "name":"Александр Кузнецов","army":0}],"history":[{"data":[5],"action":"contract","date":"2021-04-23T03:22:01.695Z"},{"data":[6],"action":"contract","date":"2021-04-23T03:04:19.733Z"},{"data":[6],"action":"contract","date":"2021-04-23T02:41:38.065Z"}], "name":"Данил Деттер","power":1,"trainCost":12,"owner":{"name":"Алексея Гребеника"},"hideButton":false}`

Если поменять на:

```
response  = get().content
```

То получаю:

```
b'1$\x12\x00 \x93:mZ{\xea\xffO\xb2+\xc9\xb6\x1c\xb9e\'\xe50\x188lz\xe2\x95\xa7_&\x84av&\xae\xa9\xff`/\xf8/\x1ey\xfed\x11\xb1\x04\x8b\x08\xef\xf3\x91\xcd*\xc0\x07<\xf6\x01\xc8\xe0\x7f\x9b\x194,A\x1c%/\xbf\x9bgz\x0f\xdc0\x0e\x14"B`,\xe6\x85\x0b-\x11P(\x04\x87\xfa\xea\xe6;L1\xc3bN&\x8c"\x06A\x17\x81\xd4\x04/n\x03\'J@A\x10\xb8_\x06J\xff\x1e\xb8\x1d\x0e\x14\x0c\x81g\xde\x93(e\x82D\x90\x08\xc1\\\x9bY\xb6\x04\x10\xabme\x1f6\xcf\xda\x03\\\xfe\xb6y\x99\xfd\xcf>\x03\x08\x96\x9e\x91X$\xe5\x8e\x85\xf1\x1csL\xe4\xab&\x8a\xda\xd2C\xff_\xc2\x9d\x04\xefx\x0e\xd9a\xd5\xe6exQ\\\x9f\xb0V\x07;w\xd6\x8dur\x95\x9e\x99\xf8z-\xf7\xb8\x93^;\x18\xdb\xa5\xb9\xa6s~\xc5]\xd6\x93\xfc\xb1*\xc4W\xf19\xae\xe6J\xe7\x8eV\xec\xa5Evm\xd4\xf2\xcb\xa0\xa0j\x95 !\x8bE\xba\xb2\xaf\xaf\xc3)\xef/\x9d\xc3\xd0\xbbk\xedc\x84n\xa3[\xabX\x9bz\xd1\x9d}Fo\x19\xeb\xc5r\x1f#\n\xb1,C\x8a\x048zoi\x89\xb6\x8f\x01\x8d*z0\x84\xe0Ad6r\xedP7P\xfa\xf2\x10\x82N=;@ao\xc1O$B\x9f\x10D0\x87D\x8e\x08\r$(\x02Q\x10\xe3)F=\xf0\x00\x1e\x83\x9b\x04\x12\x00S\x99\x84\x1b\xe5\x0b\x12\x15\xccxY\x10\x8e\x10E\xc4\x8a\x90\xe3\x11\xf5\xc4\x19F\x07$J\x88\x83\x18\xa2\xf6\xfb\xa8\x80~f\x7f\x90\xef\xb3o\x9b\xa7\x9b\xa7+<\x8e\x08\x16D\xfe\xf5!+\xae4T\xf1x\xe1\\\xc6\xc7\xf9\x84\xeb\xd2;x\xed\xac\x1bE\xae\x9e\xae\xd2\xaa:5U;\xa9\xeb"\xbe\x8b\xc2\x82\x89\x9bS\x7fa\xb6\x8b\xe7F\x01\xcf\xda\xc5\x88\xad\xcb\xebE\xd8n[\xa6\x7f\x12\xd5\xce\xeduKK\xba\xde\xdd\xab\xb3\x12\xef/\x9d\xc3\xd0\xb3V\x04\x11\xa4\x12]\xf5hX\x90\x83\xf6\xa3\xfe\x82\xba\x08EU$\x10\xe4\xc2"P\xee\xc18P`"b\x12\xc3*9\xf3m\xf3j+{\xb7y\x9c}\xeb`%\x01\xda\xe7w\xf6\x91\n\n\xf4\xed\xf9t\xd6\xb0$\x96\xcb\x17M\xfb\xfaZ.X&7\xeeZZ\xa7\x14\xda\xa6\xdb\xc53s\xee\xb7\xb1;>\x0e\xb4\xa5\xdc\xba\xd6\x16\xfe2*\x97\xef\xb6\xaf(W\xad\x869!\xf2\xcb\x17g\xc9x\xdc\xe8z\'\xc5\xa4\x1e#\xa3gX\xad;\x04\xf3\xfe\xd29\x0c=[I\x9a1A\xab:\xac\x07\xa2HL+\x17\xabi\xc4z`\x00\x03'
```

Comment: Или уберите заголовок accept-encoding или разпаковывайте данные

Comment: Спасибо большое.